# how to display unique record in combobox in C#

Tags: c#

Can any body help on this.

here i am using datasource as list for combobox.

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadDropdownlist();
        }

```
    public void LoadDropdownlist()
    {
        var makes = new List<string> {
                                       "Audi",
                                       "BMW",
                                       "Ford",
                                       "Vauxhall",
                                       "Volkswagen"
                                     };
        comboBox1.DataSource = makes;


    }
```

as per above code i am getting result in combobox as

Audi,
BMW,
Ford,
Vauxhall,
Volkswagen

but i want to display unique records based on first character.So i am expecting below result in combobox.

Audi,
BMW,
Ford,
Vauxhall

thanks,
satish

Comment: show your effort..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        public void LoadDropdownlist()
        {
            var makes = new List<string> {"Volkswagen","Audi","BMW","Ford","Vauxhall"};
            FirstLetterComparer comp = new FirstLetterComparer();
            comboBox1.DataSource=  makes.Distinct(comp).ToList();//makes.GroupBy(x=>x[0]).Select(x=>x.First()).ToList();
        }


        public class FirstLetterComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
        {
            public bool Equals(string x, string y)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(y))
                    return false;
                //ignoring case
                return string.Compare(x[0].ToString(), y[0].ToString(), 0) == 0;
            }
            public int GetHashCode(string str)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

When checking two objects for equality the following happens:

First, `GetHashCode` is called on both objects. If the hash code is different, the objects are considered not equal and `Equals` is never called.
`Equals` is only called when `GetHashCode` returned the same value for both objects.

### Solution for .Net 2

In .Net 2 you need to loop through items as this

```
    public List<string> FetchFirstLetterUniques(List<string> source)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (string item in source)
        {
            bool isAdded = false;
           foreach (string item2 in result)
           {
               if (string.Compare(item2[0].ToString(), item[0].ToString(), 0) == 0)
               {
                   isAdded = true;
                   break;
               }
           }

           if (!isAdded)
               result.Add(item);

        }

        return result;
    }

public void LoadDropdownlist()
{
    var makes = new List<string> {
                                   "Audi",
                                   "BMW",
                                   "Ford",
                                   "Vauxhall",
                                   "Volkswagen"
                                 };
    comboBox1.DataSource = FetchFirstLetterUniques(makes);


}
```

Comment: hi,thank you for your answer, can you please provide more details on the same because i am new to .net

Comment: thank you, but i am agetting error for while loading combobox

Comment: @satish what is your exception?

Comment: comboBox1.DataSource=  makes.Distinct(new FirstLetterComparer()); here i am getting error as complex databinding accepts as a data source either an IList or ILisysource

Comment: try this comboBox1.DataSource= makes.Distinct(new FirstLetterComparer()).ToList();

Comment: i have tried that one but in combobox all values loaded instead of unique values

Comment: @satish There was a minor mistake on GetHashCode, I edit my answer and it's working perfect

Comment: @satish I run the exact code on my pc and it is OK, set a break point in `Equals` to be sure it returns true if the first letters are same.

Comment: thank you. i have tested and its working fine.can you please explain what is the use of GetHashCode function.

Comment: the distict function is not there in VS2005. can u please tell me which function we can use instead of distinct

Comment: @satish so you need to loop through items and add them to another list if there is no item starting with this item first letter.

Comment: thank you so much. can you please write the code also binding combox for newly added code because i am very new to dotnet.

Comment: hi,if i am taking List<comboxitem> then how could be fond the unique entries based on first character.

Comment: hi, please tell me if we take the List<comboxitem> then how can we find the duplicates

Comment: hi, by duplicate, do you mean first letters duplicate? and why don't you use the combo.DataSource (since in your sample it is List<string>)

Comment: actually in my project they are using list<comboxitem> that's why i have to use that only....

Answer (score 0):

You can group them based on first characters:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = makes
                      .GroupBy(x => x[0])
                      .Select(x => x.First())
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for u answer. But i have to work on C#2.0, there is no lamda expressions in C#2.0, is there any alaternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  var makes = new List<string> {
                                       "Audi",
                                       "BMW",
                                       "Ford",
                                       "Vauxhall",
                                       "Volkswagen"
                                     }.GroupBy(t => t[0])
                .Select(t => t.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: hi,Lambda expressions are not working in c#2.0, can u please give me any other solution?